# Python: How to iterate over a dict object dynamically?

Tags: python, loops, formatting

I want to write so data to a file, but the data can vary depending on its source.

At the moment my code just does the following:

```
try:
    file.write('{value1}'.format(value1=data["value1"]))
except:
    pass

try:
    file.write('{value2}'.format(value2=data["value2"]))
except:
    pass

#...
```

Due to the nature of the input data, these value keys may or may not be present, hence why I'm doing the above so when I get a KeyError I can just ignore it.

So my question is, is there a better way of doing the above? A more 'pythonic' way rather than this pretty wet solution?

example_input1:

```
'{"value1": 1.0, "value2": 1.2}'
```

example_input2:

```
'{"value2": 1.5}'
```

I guess ultimately I should standardise the input data, but unfortunately this is coming from a third-party API so isn't really an option.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can simply use:

```
for key in ('value1','value2'):
    if key in data:
        file.write('{}'.format(data[key]))
```

So here `if key in data` first checks if there is a key in the dictionary (e.g. `'value1'`). Given that is the case, we use `file.write('{}'.format(data[key]))` to write the corresponding value to the file.

The advantage of using a `for` loop is furthermore that you can easily add and remove keys you want to print from the file.

If on the other hand you wish to `write` **all keys** that are in the dictionary, you can **iterate over the dictionary**:

```
for val in data.values():
    file.write('{}'.format(val))
```

Mind however that the *order* of the key/values in a dictionary is not necessary the insertion order. So the values can be shuffled.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `json` library to convert your input string into dictionary-like object.

```
>>> import json
>>> input1 = '{"value1": 1.0, "value2": 1.2}'
>>> input2 = '{"value2": 1.5}'
>>> input1 = json.loads(input1)
>>> input2 = json.loads(input2)
>>> for key in input1.keys():
...  print(input1[key])
... 
1.2
1.0
>>> for key in input2.keys():
...  print(input2[key])
... 
1.5
```

Answer (score 1):

If the order is not important in your case, you can just loop over your data like below:

```
for v in data.values():
    file.write('{}'.format(v))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> data = {"value1": 1.0, "value2": 1.2}
>>> for v in data.values():
...     print(v)
...
1.2
1.0
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends, but I think you don't want to write all data you got, but only some one *if they exists*.

So here is a pythonic way (`try` / `except`):

```
inputs = [
    {"value1": "foo", "value2": "bar"},
    {"value1": "foo"},
    {"value3": "baz", 'unexpected': '??'}
]

expected_keys = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']

for data in inputs:
    for key in expected_keys:
        try:
            file.write(data[key])
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

`inputs` is just a list of `dict` used as example, `expected_keys` is a list of keys you want to write if they exists in inputs.

With that you never miss an existing key and never raise `KeyError` if a key is missing.

**This is the real pythonic way to handle this, see [Python's EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp)**